# How to access values from Android "strings.xml" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

How can I access values from the Android **strings.xml** using Kotlin?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        getToastCalled("")
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    private fun getToastCalled(message: String) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    var btn: Button? = null;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var tv_name=findViewById(R.id.tv) as TextView
        btn=findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
        tv_name.setText(KtTest().name);
        (btn as Button).setOnClickListener(MainActivity@this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just like in Java.

Comment: You've already referenced layouts and ids in your example. Also keep in mind that you can convert java files to kotlin using ctrl + shift + alt + k. There is also extensive documentation on methods available on kotl.in

Comment: thanx alot for help..

Answer (score 126):

Accessing string values in Kotlin works exactly the same as it does in Java, just with Kotlin syntax:

```
val string: String = getString(R.string.your_string_id)
```

(This assumes that your code is inside an Android `Activity`, or a similar class that inherits from `Context`. If not, you need to get a `Context` instance from somewhere, and change it to `myContext.getString(...)`.)

Comment: This could produce **null**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Well, yeah, technically it could, but that's a programming error or something's wrong with the build process if it does. This call returning null isn't something you could recover from in any meaningful way, so in Java, null is never checked here, and you luckily you don't need to in Kotlin either.

Comment: I tried to use this function, Android Studio couldn't even find it

Comment: @RowanBerry `getString` is defined on `Context`. My example code was written assuming you're inside an Android `Activity`, which inherits from `Context`, but if you need it somewhere else, you need to have a `Context` available somewhere. You need to change the example it to `myContext.getString(...)` in that case.
(Disclaimer - haven't done Android development for a long time now, details might have changed)

Comment: @Robin yeah i figured that out after writing my comment, was trying to do it in an object class, just wasn't explicitly stated

Comment: Yeah, I guess it might trip others up as well. I've added the clarification to the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 26):

if you're accessing it outside oncreate then

```
    Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.btn_yes)
```

Answer (score 11):

If you need to access the entire array:

```
val data= resources.getStringArray(R.array.array_id)
```

Answer (score 8):

If it helps this is how I did it - you need the application context and also to import the R Class

```
applicationContext.getString(R.string.text_string)
import com.example.yourpackagename.R
```

Answer (score 3):

To use strings.xml in my code I do the following:
`textView.text = "${getString(R.string.my_text)}"`

Answer (score 2):

In my recyclerview adapter, inside the ViewHolder class, I reference to string.xml like this;

```
binding.myText.setText(R.string.my_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Robin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44901859/10749567) almost worked for me, but if I don't add `this.resources` before the `getString(R.string.tv)` my app just keeps crashing.

So to access a string value from within the ***strings.xml*** file in ***Kotlin*** use:
`this.resources.getString(R.string.tv)`

Or simply:
`resources.getString(R.string.tv)`

Answer (score 1):

you can access string value in kotlin by

```
  val string:String = resources.getString(R.string.variable_name)
```

or use

```
val string: String = getString(R.string.variable_name)
```

For more details, you can refer to the [Android developer documents](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource)

Answer (score 0):

Use the format - R.string.string_name

Reference it explicitly for example:

```
R.string.loadingText,
```

Given your XML file has the following as part of the resources:

```
<string name="loadingText">The actual text to be displayed</string>
```

Comment: Doesn't this return the integer id of that XML string, rather than the string content itself?

Answer (score 0):

I used it for titlebar, but my app crashed.

```kotlin
private var title: String = getString(R.string.profile)
```

Comment: Separate the declaration and usage like 
private var title: String 
and in onCreate method or any other method where you want to access 
title = "${getString(R.string.

Answer (score 0):

You can access string values simply through - `"@string/variable_name"`.

For instance - if strings.xml contains entry like `<string name="app_name">Tip Time</string>`, then you can access it using -

```
"@string/app_name"
```

Comment: That's in XML files.  But what about in Kotlin files?