# Android - while debugging, can't evaluate getString() from resources

Tags: java, android, debugging, kotlin, evaluate

so, I'm trying to debug my app, and i'm evaluating expression with following code line:

```java
resources.getString(R.string.my_string);
```

I should get my string from strings.xml, but I get an error:

```java
Method threw 'android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException' exception.
```

Someone know why can't I approach resources while evaluating?

[here you can see what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEvcG.png)

Thx to all! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access values from strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871481/how-to-access-values-from-strings-xml)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to evaluating the resources:

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.my_string);
```

or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/how-can-i-get-a-resource-content-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811) for local resources.

Comment: same error.
it seems like you can't evaluate local resources, but don't know why

Comment: The line is working properly, but when evaluating expression on that line, i don't get string.

Comment: Have you tried this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/how-can-i-get-a-resource-content-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing.
I thing it's not problem in code, but in android studio. Seems like it's not allowed evaluating resources.

Comment: I am using android studio 4.0, it's working for me.

Comment: you are evaluating expression while debugging?

Comment: by evaluate expression, i think of:
- stop while debugging
- right click -> evaluate expression
- try evaluate resources.getString...
- error

Comment: fins the screenshot link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/16N_PKWGiZc-1qeyNJvmUJxKiesXy9Jtv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

if you are in an activity `val string: String = getString(R.string.your_string_id)`
if some where else pass the context to that method then `myContext.getString(...)`

Comment: i know that, but i think it's not problem in code. code works fine, and if I didn't stop while debugging and tried evaluate expression, i would't ever know I can't evaluate local resources.

Comment: but i don't know why I can't evaluate local resources.
is it connected with kotlin, maybe android studio...don't know :(